# How to pass parameter for sorting in sequelize.query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have used sequelize and had to write a custom `SELECT` query. I also have to perform sorting based on the parameter passed by user. So I decided to use `replacements`. The query looks something like this:

```
sequelize.query(
      "SELECT SUM(amount), ...... FROM table1 GROUP BY address ORDER BY SUM(:orderBy);", {
      replacements: { orderBy: "amount" }
    })
```

The problem is sequelize seems to pass `amount` as string rather than as identifer. So I am getting the following error:

```
Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts
```

How can I resolve it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by using `replacements` or `bind` options.
You can either use a string concatenation (the worst case scenario that might lead to SQL injection) or try to convert this query to a query against a Sequelize model with some custom attributes in the query.

Comment: I am able to pass limit and offset using `bind`. Why is it only that ORDER BY cannot be passed?

Comment: Because in `limit` and `offset` you pass a concrete value unlike `order` where you're trying to pass a column name. Column names can be used only if you use a model query.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure that you need custom query at all, you always can try:

```js
const result = await Table1Model.findAll({
    replacements: ["amount"],
    attributes: [
        "id",
        [sequelize.literal('(SELECT SUM(amount)::int FROM "table1" WHERE "table1"."x" = "table2"."x")'), 'total_amount'],
    ],
    order: sequelize.literal(`? DESC`),
})
```